# Emacs: region isn't highlighted when selected with keyboard

Tags: emacs, configuration, highlighting

When I select a region by clicking and dragging a mouse across the text, the selection shows up highlighted, as expected. However, when I do the same by hitting `M-<space>` to set the mark, then moving the point with the arrow keys, the region doesn't show up highlighted. I can yank it, but I can't call things like `replace-string` on it, suggesting that the region is not active.

[This guy](http://promberger.info/linux/2011/09/08/emacs-22-does-not-highlight-region/) seems to have encountered a similar problem in emacs 22 (I'm using 23), and his fix was to call `M-x transient-mark-mode` to enable that mode. Unfortunately, I already have `(custom-set-variables '(transient-mark-mode t))` in my .emacs file. Indeed, when I run `M-x transient-mark-mode`, I get the message "`transient-mark-mode disabled`", suggesting that it had been enabled before.

Any suggestions as to what might be going on, or things I could try to shed more light on the situation, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you put this in your conf file ? 

    (custom-set-variables 
     '(transient-mark-mode t)
    )

Comment: @Antzi Yep. I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: What happen when you launch emacs -q then ?

Comment: Turn on transient-mark-mode "again" with M-x. That seems to have fix the problem in my case.

Comment: @Antzi: yep, the region is properly active if I run emacs -q. aartist: running M-x transient-mark-mode twice to toggle the mode off and on again didn't fix the problem, sadly.

Comment: There is probably something with your conf file then, can you put it on pastebin ?

Answer (score 0):

Bisect your init file (~/.emacs) until you find the culprit code.  You just need to make sure `transient-mark-mode` is turned on only once.  You can also just put `(setq transient-mark-mode t)` at the end of your init file.  Unless actions you take interactively cause some other library to be loaded that changes the value of that variable, that should ensure that the mode is on.

The first thing to try, however, is just `M-x transient-mark-mode`, to be sure that the mode actually works for you.  If not, again, bisect your init file to find out what breaks it.